# Двойной цикл foreach

Tags: php

Есть две директории: `/resource/images/foto_gallery/miniature/` и `/resource/images/foto_gallery/`

В первой директории хранятся изображения в миниатюре, а во второй — эти же изображения, только в нормальном размере.

Мне нужно вывести на страницу сначала изображения в миниатюре с помощью цикла foreach, и чтобы по нажатию на миниатюру она раскрывалась до нормального размера.

Миниатюры я вывел, но мне надо перебрать изображения из директории `/resource/images/foto_gallery/` и вставить их в html-код. Для директории с миниатюрами у меня получилось, а вот с нормальными изображениями не выходит.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать.

Вот сам код:

```
function content_portfolio(){       
        foreach(glob("./resource/images/foto_gallery/miniature/"."*.jpg") as $filename){
            $content .= '
            <div id="lightgallery" class="gallery">         
                <div class="image" data-src="/resource/images/foto_gallery/foto-1.jpg">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="'.$filename.'">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }
        return $content;
    }
```

Comment: Как у вас хранится информацию о том какая миниатюрка к какому изображению? В базе или просто названия одинаковые например?

Answer (score 1):

Для наглядности заменил html на простой вывод в строку. В данном примере предполагается, что миниатюра называется `thumb_image`, где `image` - название полного изображения. Расширение миниатюр и изображений не учитывается.

```
<?php
    $content = '';
    foreach(new DirectoryIterator('./') as $item) {
        if ($item->isFile()) {
            $thumb = str_replace(
                ".{$item->getExtension()}",
                '',
                $item->getFilename()
            );
            $image = findImage($thumb, './');
            $content = sprintf(
                'thumb: %s image: %s ' . PHP_EOL,
                $item->getFilename(),
                $image
            );
            echo $content;
        }
    }

    function findImage($thumb, $dir) {
        $find = false;
        $imageIterator = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
        while (
                !$find &&
                $imageIterator->valid()
            ) {
            $imageIterator->next();
            if ($imageIterator->isFile()) {
                $find = compare(
                    $thumb,
                    str_replace(
                        ".{$imageIterator->getExtension()}",
                        '',
                        $imageIterator->getFilename()
                    )
                );
            }
        }
        return $imageIterator->valid()
            ? $imageIterator->getFileName()
            : '';
    }

    function compare($thumb, $image) {
        return (('thumb_' . $image) == $thumb);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну информация конечно исчерпывающая. Смотря как связаны миниатюры и изображения.
Если по имени, то и добавляйте в цикле к имени что нужно `<img src="min'.$filename.'">`
Если нет, то и организовывать так, как они организованы изначально

Answer (score 0):

Если количество и порядок миниатюр и картинок гарантированно совпадает, то вы можете взять два их массива и пройтись по ним одним счетчиком:

```
$content = '';
$min = glob("./resource/images/foto_gallery/miniature/*.jpg");
$max = glob("./resource/images/foto_gallery/*.jpg");
if (count($min) != count($max)) {
    // Что-то пошло не так, количество разное
    return $content;
}
for ($i = 0; $i < count($min); $i++) {
    $content .= '
    <div id="lightgallery" class="gallery">         
        <div class="image" data-src="'.$max[$i].'">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="'.$min[$i].'">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
return $content;
```

Answer (score -1):

Я бы порекомендовал Вам изменить немного структуру(если такое возможно). Например полное изображение имеет имя "filename.jpg", а превью - "filename-min.jpg".
Тогда, получив все превью, Вам останется получить лишь имя файла, допустим через регулярное выражение и найти(или нет) полное изображение в нужной Вам папке.
Немного изменив структуру Вы избежите постоянной нагрузки на сервер, который при каждом вызове будет запускать цикл и искать изображение, которое, не факт, что и найдет.

```
<php 
$preview = 'filename-min.jpg'; 
$file = preg_match('/^(?:\w*)/', $preview, $matches);
if(glob($matches[0].'.jpg')){
//тут пишете код для отображения
}
```